# Configuration of php-debug plugin in Atom

Tags: php, xdebug, atom-editor

I am trying to integrate debugging feature(`xDebug`) in Atom editor. Now I am stuck at `PHP-debug` configuration. I want to set `local` and `remote` path to configure `PHP-debug` extension but I don't know what is it mean by `local` and `remote` path.

I am using `XAMPP` server on my MAC machine can anyone please help me to configure it?

**Updates**

Here are the links to my tutorials:-
https://atom.io/packages/php-debug
https://luminfire.com/2016/08/19/configure-atoms-php-debug-package-work-xdebug-pressmatic-site/

From the tutorials, I found out that below is the definition for `local` and `remote` path

- The Path to your site’s public directory from the perspective of your
  local machine i.e. Local Path
- The Path to your site’s public directory from the perspective of your
  virtual machine i.e. Remote Path

But I am new to server side I can't understand what is this means. Can anyone please help me to configure it?

Comment: I don't get the details about the Local and Remote path. But from this tutorial https://hubpages.com/technology/Local-PHP-Debugging-with-XDebug-Atom-and-XAMPP I understand that we can make it empty if we are developing in local. So now its works like a charm